# How to have a relationship between two tables having one to one relatioship with another

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have two entities, bungalows and apartments. Both these entities have multiple tenants, but each tenant can only be part of either one bungalow or one apartment. How do I achieve this using entity framework.

I was thinking of creating 2 more entities bungalowTenants and apartmentTenants and using these to map. 
Each bungalowTenant would have one instance of a bungalow and a tenant and similar for apartmentTenant.

Bungalows would have a collection of bungalowTenants and apartment of apartmentTenants.

The problem with this approach is that it does not restrict in any way the same tenant to be a part of both, a bungalow and an apartment. I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: `Bungalows` and `Apartments` can be saved to same table say, `Properties` with inheritance with Table per Hierarchy model . Then in `PropertyTenants` table, you can have tenant Id and Property Id as composite primary key which will achieve your relationships and restrictions. Property base entity will be abstract and will have Tenants collection.

Comment: I cannot save bungalows and apartments in same tables. They have different fields and are used in the application for different purposes.